# долгая загрузка модели нейронной сети

Tags: php, python

есть нейронная сеть, она является чат-ботом.
с сайта отправляется ajax-запрос на php, он через `shell_exec` запускает питон и получает от него ответ, который после отправляет клиенту. проблема в том что всё это работает очень долго, но самое узкое место в самом питоне.

замеряю время этой функцией:

```
start_time = time.clock() #начали считать
#код
q = time.clock() - start_time #закончики считать
return_(q) #функция ответа и завершения
```

в целом код отрабатывает быстро, в среднем 0.0001 сек. (без загрузки модели), но как только я возвращаю загрузку модели (`model = load_model( mycfg.path + 'my_model.h5')`), то время выполнения в среднем становится 1.18 сек., при этом сама модель имеет размер 67кб.

для чата такая скорость непозволительна, особенно учитывая потерю времени на прослойку в виде php, каким образом оптимизировать этот момент? может можно запустить сеть в фоновом режиме и работать с процессом, а не грузить каждый раз всё для работы с сетью?

Comment: сделайте [сервис на Python](https://medium.com/@umerfarooq_26378/web-services-in-python-ef81a9067aaf), который будет постоянно работать и отвечать на запросы. Все необходимые модули и обученная модель будут находиться в пямяти...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы уже сами ответили на свой вопрос - можно запустить сеть и работать с загруженными данными, модулями и т.п. Я бы воспользовался [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), делаем простое серверное приложение, которое по урлу ждет фразу пользователя, при получении фразы отдает ее на обработку нейросети и возвращает ответ.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/get_phrase/<ph>')
def get_phrase(ph):
    ans = some_do(ph)
    return jsonify({'answer': ans})

def some_do(ph):
    # work
    return result
```

Comment: сделал, а как лучше обращаться к нему с клиента? с ajax проблемы из за кроссбраузерности(другой порт считается другим доменом), с .htaccess не получается, redirect отправляет заголовки браузеру, не перенаправляет запрос без ответа клиенту. как лучше это сделать?

Comment: Я работаю с nginx, почти не имел дел с .htaccess, не подскажу, попробуйте задать такой вопрос сообществу

Answer (score 1):

В дополонению ответа про сервер вы можете попытаться взаимодействовать через 'std*'
Например:
(сторона питона):

```
model = init_model()
while True:
    print(model.get_output(input()))
```

(сторона php)

```
1. инициализация процесса
2. отправить ему текст
3. получить его выход
```